# How does one add multiple HDDs to a server already at max?

Tags: hard-drive

How does one add multiple HDDs to a server already at max?

I'm just trying to wrap my head around this without drawing extreme solutions.

If I have a budget server that has 5 x 4TB HDDs and I add two SATA controllers to the only existing MOBO slots and swap out the PS plus add the necessary cables and connectors ... And now I'm at "max" ... And there's hard drives dangling and sitting in every mouse corner ....

Leap ...

What's the best choice? To keep them all under the same OS and license and not drop performance by going to external "boxes"?

Please don't resort to SATA controller w/### number of connectors.

What's the most professional set of choices: meaning what does a company do (I'm not a company) when it needs more physical space but not a new OS to go with it and needs to keep data speed consistent (so no cloud storage)?

Thank you

May you be granted three wishes for helping me get clear on this.

Comment: Buy a new server or new external hdd enclosure. You don't really have many more options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a budget server, you're not getting much speed out of it anyways. I'm going to assume that the server provides filespace for your "office" and that what you need is more filespace.

As Lawrence said, you buy an external enclosure and live with the slight loss of speed or you get another server.

You could try to upgrade the drives, replacing them with larger versions, but that's, um dangerous if you're on a budget. (You need more space on a budget, so you obviously don't have enough now to keep a full backup of everything. Upgrading drives in place on a raid without a backup is your last resort, and may not work at all.)

Perhaps if you gave more information on the purpose of the server and the constraints under which you operate, it would help to get a better answer.